# what is the proper way to get my google account profile image (URL) in NodeJS

Tags: google-oauth

see below error message and source code, doesn't work even after I added person fields of photos:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'url')

var p = google.people("v1");
p.people.get(
  {
    resourceName: "people/me",
    personFields: "names,emailAddresses,photos",
    auth: oauth2Client,
  },
  function (err, user) {
    if (err) { return; }
    res.json({
      name: encoder.htmlEncode(user.displayName),
      picture: user.image.url,
    });
  }
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have a look into the docs. The [`people.get`](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people/get) request returns a [`Person`](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people#Person) object. And such a `Person` does not have an `image` property, so you cant't access `user.image.url` because `user.image` does not exist. Neither does `user.displayName`, btw.

What a `Person` actually looks like is as follows (the `...` meaning there are additional properties too, look up in the docs, if you need more)

```
{
   ...
  coverPhotos: [{url: "https://url.to/image", ...}],
  ...
  names: [{ displayName: "John Doe", ...}],
  ...
}
```

So to get the `name` and `picture`, first of all, instead of `photos` you need to request `coverPhotos`. Then you can extract the desired values, as follow:

```
p.people.get(
  {
    resourceName: "people/me",
    personFields: "names,emailAddresses,coverPhotos",
    auth: oauth2Client,
  },
  function (err, user) {
    if (err) { return; }
    let 
      name = user.names?.[0]?.displayName || "John Doe",
      url = user.coverPhotos?.[0]?.url
    
    res.json({
      name: encoder.htmlEncode(name),
      picture: user.image.url,
    });
  });
```

I used the conditional chaining `?.` here, to make sure, this code does not run into an exception if for instance `coverPhotos` does not exist or is an empty array.

Comment: If that works for you, please don't forget to accept the anwser. BTW, this seems to be inside an express route handler. So you should also send an appropriate response to the client in case of an error.